# Cannot get bottom view in three js scene

Tags: three.js

[image]

In this scene when Orthographic is selected, all the views work except "Bottom"; it produces different views depending on the predecessor.

Here is the view function:

```
function fView(name){
  let p = mset.view[name];
  let cam = "Orthographic";
  mset.camera.position[cam] = p;
  camera.position.set(p[0],p[1],p[2]);
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  camera.lookAt(scene.position);
}
```

Here is mset json

```
"view":{
    "Top":[0,1,0],
    "Bottom":[0,-1,0],
    "Front":[0,0,1],
    "Back":[0,0,-1],
    "Left":[-1,0,0],
    "Right":[1,0,0]
  }
```

Comment: Try resetting the camera's `quaternion` value before computing the new projection matrix. `camera.quaternion.identity();`

Comment: Sorry for delay; I have so may little problems like this, I decided to try and deal with them comprehensively; https://discourse.threejs.org/t/three-js-and-tba/29764 is a start.